# Canvas JS causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, canvasjs

I am creating a line graph in canvas js. It has the following dataset

```
    dataPoints: [//array
    {x: new Date(Date.UTC (2012, 00, 1, 1,0) ), y: 26 },
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC (2012, 00, 1,2,0) ), y: 38  },
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,3,0) ), y: 43 },
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,4,0) ), y: 29},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,5,0) ), y: 41},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,6,0) ), y: 54},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,7,0) ), y: 66},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,8,0) ), y: 60},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,9,0) ), y: 53},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 00, 1,10,0) ), y: 60}
    ]
  }
  ]
```

I understand the 1,2,3 parameters in `Date.UTC()` but I don't understand the 4th and 5th parameters. What are these? I am using

> http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/date-time-axis/
>   Under the heading **Converting in Local Time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) can be under this form:

```
Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])
```

so in your example:

```
{x: new Date(Date.UTC (2012, 00, 1, 1,0) ), y: 26
```

2012 is the year,
00 is the month,
1 is the day,
1 is the hour,
0 is the minute.
Please **notice** that only year and month are needed while all other parameters are optional.

Comment: Can I convert a timestamp that is already in miliseconds into `Sat Dec 01 2012 11:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)` ?

Comment: you can do whatever you want with Date.parse. Mark this as answer if it helped you solve your problem.